# Why does the find method refer to the model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie wondering why the find method is called on the Article class but not the instanced model.

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

It makes sense to me to do `Article.new` since we are instantiating an object from the Article class but why do we call the find method on the Article class even for `Article.all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Article` is associated with the whole collection. And it is logical to have `find` on `Collection` to find a record from the collection. It is more clearly than having `Article.new.load(params[:id])`.

More than that it's considered to be a common practice, consider next example:

```
class Article
  @@instances = []

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @@instances << self
  end

  def self.find(name)
    @@instances.find { |i| i.name == name }
  end
end

article = Article.new('New Article')
Article.find('New Article') #=> #<Article:0x00000001668040>
```

About Rails. `find` is one of those methods which can be called on a model or on a `Relation`. Some of those methods do even return `Relation`, for example  `all`, `where`, `order`, `limit` and `offset`. And it is nice because you can form a chain:

```
Article.where(..) #=> Relation
Article.where(..).find(12) #=> record with id: 12 satisfying some additional requirements
```